# Does client side pagination contributes to Visualforce view state size or governor limits?

Tags: pagination, viewstate

i am using client side pagination using datatable. Does it affect my view state size and other visualforce page governor limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. Only Visualforce elements and controller instance data contribute to the view state. As long as you use a remote action or some other mechanism that doesn't rely on instance data or Visualforce elements, you can load as much as the browser can handle. If you build the table with Visualforce, then it will contribute to view state.

Comment: I realized I had to clarify. Make sure you look at the update.